# 12.04 Installation went wrong

Tags: re-installation

I am not very familiar with all the process of installing Ubuntu and the how-it-works, but one of my friends had shown me how to install Ubuntu 10.something on a partition (I have Windows 7 on the other one) and it worked nicely, and since then I've been using Ubuntu. The upgrade from 10 to 11 went just fine, but when going from 11 to 12.04, my computer crashed in the middle (I don't remember why). But now I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I constantly have this red disk with a white dash in it on my desktop bar reminding me that I have a System Problem. I believe re-installing Ubuntu 12.04 (if my computer doesn't crash during the installation this time) would work, but I don't know how to do this. So here is the question :

How would I re-install Ubuntu 12.04? Is there a guide out there for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just run the Ubuntu LiveCD again and repeat the installation process. Make sure you install it on a separate partition.

Comment: There is [official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) for dual booting with windows. Go through it , after that clarify your doubts here before installing so it will be easy and quick.

Comment: @tijybba : I am really confused with that kind of page. Too much information, and I am way too scared to destroy my computer (i.e. do so much trouble on it that I need to format it and start from scratch) by following those steps. If I had a "test computer I could anything on", I wouldn't mind trying, but with all my precious information & programs installed on my computer I wouldn't dare screwing everything up. It doesn't mean that I don't have a back up, it just means that it takes a lot of time to fix those things.

Comment: I'll try downloading Ubuntu Desktop and see if there's a "re-install" option... would that be a good option?

Comment: Yes just don't format or select any option if you don't understand its consequences just ask here .

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu/145652#145652 in concert with the answer below it with the screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to post some Important steps with screenshots , here you go.

**Boot** from **Live Usb Drive or Live Cd** of **Ubuntu 12.04.**

Select the **Try Before Install** option ( *take back up before proceeding if required*), then at the desktop select the **Install Ubuntu 12.04** option.

[image]

Select the Language from **Left Side** menu, and **Continue**

Then make sure you have Internet Connection ,don't select anything & **Continue**

[image]

Then At this Below image Menu select the Last option *( Other options Might Vary to that of yours)*  **Something Else** ,& **continue**.

[image]

You will be brought to Partition table , **Most important** step also,

Select the Partition Your current Ubuntu installation is On , most probably will be with **ext4** ( or ext3 ) type and verify its size if you know it  , if you can't recognize then Open the **Dash** and search for **Disk Utility** & maximize it, select your hard drive , and search & select the **ext4** or **ext3** partition , you will find its appropriate **/dev/sdaX** number , now Back in Installation menu , **Tick mark** the Square Box to **Format** it , & select the **Mount Point** as **/**  only ,stating root partition.

Since you are re-installing, so i am  assuming that you already have **swap** partition present as from below image.

**Don't click Install now** yet , see the **Device for boot loader installation** option , preferably select **/dev/sda** without any **number** adjoining it.

[image]

Now you can **Cross-check** the partition and booting option , and Select **Install now** to go forward. Further options are pretty simple , they don't need instructions.

Hope your installation successfully finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Your're right, reinstalling sounds like a good idea in your case. I'd suggest you checked out the Ubuntu Manual. You can download it [here](http://ubuntu-manual.org/) and it covers the installation process in depth starting in chapter 2 (I believe). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, reinstalling sounds like the best option, here is a guide as requested :

First boot the live cd and select `try ubuntu`.

When it has loaded open `disk utility` and click on your hard disk,
then click on the partition you want to install to (you should recognise it by the size or ext file system),
just below you should see `device` followed by something like `/dev/sda2`
and so `sda2` would be the partition to install to.

Next click the `install ubuntu` icon on the desktop,
select the bottom option `something else`.
You will then be able to select which partition to install to,
which will be called sda2 (or whatever you saw earlier in disc utility).

Click on that partition and select `change` then select `format as ext4` and give it a mount point of `/`.

Finally click install at the bottom.