# 12.04 LTS won't boot. No boot option. Installed along side vista 64 ultimate

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-vista

I installed 12.04 LTS on my computer that already had Vista 64 Ultimate.  Installation said that reboot was necesarry to use the new installation.  Well, it just boots right into vista without giving me a boot option for ubuntu.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I've installed and used ubuntu in the past, but I still consider myself a newbie.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The installation recommended a drive, and partitioned it.  I'm not sure what would be considered "advanced partitioning."  Could you give me a little direction on how I "install the bootloader to /dev/sda?"

Comment: In the place where you chose the option to install side-by-side, there was an option for "something else". Also, you don't need to reinstall. I will add an answer soon.

Comment: You can refer the Bootloader option in the last image [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/161271/63025).

Comment: These first two answers are very much appreciated, BUT when I boot from cd and select "try Ubuntu" I end up at a colorful ubuntu desktop background with nothing else.  No task bar or anything.  As if it started the load and stopped.  No Ctr+ALT+F1 or Ctr+Alt+F6.   :(   Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to open terminal without going in to  "Try Ubuntu?"

Comment: Yes. Sorry for slow response. Boot as far as it'll take you, and press <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F1> to get into TTY1. Use <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F7> to get back into the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to repair GRUB.

1. To do this, boot from any Live CD and open a terminal.
2. Mount the partition with your installed Ubuntu by entering

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda? /mnt
   ```

   Important: replace the '?' with the partition where you installed Ubuntu!
   If you don't know which partition this is, open gparted and look for it.
3. Include the directory with important device information

   ```
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   ```

   and /sys

   ```
   sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```

   and the interface data

   ```
   sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
   ```
4. Now change into the mounted system:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   ```
5. Then you can install GRUB by typing

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

   and

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

   If you get Errors with the last step, just mention it in a comment.
6. Exit the terminal with `exit`.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: on sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev and sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys I get a message that says the following:  mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist.  Same with /mnt/sys

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that you have to replace the '?' in the command `sudo mount /dev/sda? /mnt` with the partition you want to repair / install GRUB on. I improved it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help (and the correction)  it worked!!!  I'm so happy to have ubuntu up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Please boot your installation CD and select to "try Ubuntu". Then, open a terminal by searching for "Terminal" in the launcher. Then, run the following command, one-by-one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then, run `boot-repair` from the terminal.
 Use the "Recommended repair", and it will do a repair and give you a URL(If it prompts you to install `pastebinit`, then do so. Please post the URL here.

Also, if you get worried about Windows doing a chkdsk, read the following quote:

> It should be noted for those new to Linux though that when you start Windows after using this tool it will run chkdisk on the windows partition, so don't panic.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This did not work for me.  I had error messages after the second process.  Unfortunately I did not write them down to share.  I remember to do that next time.

Comment: The error messages about Glib and pixmaps and stuff are useless and you can safely continue(it takes a while). If you have *other* errors, do tell.